# How do you feel about the use of the first indefinite article in: "A computer is a very useful tool"?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it ungrammatical? 
Unacceptable? 
Would you say a phrase like this? and if so, in what context? Do you need a clear context to say it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Frankly, I've never become emotionally involved with an indefinite article.

Comment: @HotLicks It is better to have loved indefinitely than to have never loved at all.

Comment: A turtle lives 'twixt plated decks/ I think it clever of the turtle/ In such a fix/ to be so fertile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Few Notes on Generic Reference](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147367/a-few-notes-on-generic-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically it's correct, and talking about context, it could be used if you are talking with a person who doesn't know what a computer is, an you say "A computer is a very useful tool..."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "(...) it could be used if you are talking with a person who doesn't know what a computer is (...)": That is exactly what I thought it could be related to. There is a debate on the generic use of "a(n)" in the position of subject before the verb, and I wasn't sure about how this sentence would be taken. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly grammatical and colloquial.  It means that computers, as a concept or as a whole, are useful tools, but it might be that the speaker is implying that the listener should acquire a computer

"*The* computer is a …" would either mean the former, or it might be referring to a specific computer being useful.