# 'the' usage : used to mark a noun as being used generically

Tags: meaning, word-usage, definite-articles, determiners, general-vs-specific

**The question:**

The definite article 'the' has many usages. However, I cannot quite understand one usage, that is, 'used to mark a noun as being used generically'. What does it mean by 'noun being used generically'? Can anyone please shed some light on this and set some examples.

An example for this use is 'The dog is a quadruped.'

How can I  distinguish if the author is expressing a generic noun/idea instead of specifying something in front of 'the'?

---

<sup>**Readers Note:**</sup>

<sup>Readers interested in this question might like this question here:</sup>

<sup>- [A query about the use of Generic Reference with nationalities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147367/a-few-notes-on-generic-reference)</sup>

<sup>That question is about using generic noun phrases with nationalities.</sup>

Comment: 'The dog is vicious; it has bitten several people' uses _the_ to specify one particular dog (the one that is under discussion). // 'The dog is a quadruped' is just another way of saying 'Dogs are four-legged animals' (ignoring, of course, the odd sad case).

Comment: 'The dog' as a species is a quadruped.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Can you have a look at another question I came up with? Is the second case a generic reference?https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/411722/approximations-to-solutions-vs-approximations-to-the-solution?noredirect=1#comment982212_411722

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have known of  there are three types of generic references to nouns. However, for specific usages in certain a context, I still cannot quite distinguish the author was using a generic reference or he was specifying something when I met 'the' plus a singular noun.

Comment: The linked-to question doesn't seem like a duplicate. There is an answer by John Lawler buried in there. However, it does not explain what is mean by generic apart from to say they are used as a way of "positing some proposition over a set". Instead he gives three different grammatical forms that a generic NP may take. Please, let's reopen this question.

Comment: @Araucaria Yes. I need someone to provide dedicated weapons to help me distinguish if the author is expressing a generic noun/idea instead of specifying something in front of  'the'.

Comment: @AndyT I've been editing reopen notes into questions for eons and removing them after the question has been reopened. No-ones ever complained :) I'm going to edit it back in. It's a reopen note explaining why the question is not a dupe, not a discussion, old bean

Comment: @AndyT I'll delete it of course when the Q gets reopened :)

Comment: @Araucaria - You're probably right. In fact, writing what you've found elsewhere and explaining why it doesn't answer your question is in fact what we ask for in questions! I withdraw my previous objection (but quite like being called "old bean") :D

Comment: My first comment here indicated that context (non-verbal where appropriate, but verbal in many cases) is used to distinguish generic from specifying usage. For a usage to be the specifying one, there must be previous (non-verbal or verbal) identification of the individual animal / object / ...  involved. // "positing some proposition over a set" means making a general statement about a whole class (apart from outliers like amputee dogs). The dog is a quadruped / dogs are quadrupeds / a dog is a quadruped. / {dogs} ⊂ {quadrupeds}.

Comment: What is verbal identification?